# Rails 4.2.0 Likes, like button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-like

I was trying to implement possibility of Liking posts on my website but I have failed to do so. After clicking on "Like" the count of likes does not grow.

This is my button in view (partial).

```
    <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post, like: true), method: 'post' %>
    <%= pluralize( post.likes.size, "like") %>
```

And my models:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  ...
 end
```

User:

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Like action in posts controller:

```
def like
    Like.create(user: current_user, like: params[:like])
    flash[:success] = "Like Counted!"
    redirect_to :back
end
```

routes:

```
resources :posts do
    member do
        post 'like'
    end
end
```

And my migration:
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord:: Migration

```
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
            t.boolean :like, :default => false
      t.references :likeable, polymorphic: true
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I have used polymorphic because I am planning to add ability to Like comments as well.

Comment: I have found answer to my problem shortly after i added this post but decidec not to delete it so someone could get help. I simply added: post = Post.find(params[:id])
Like.create(likeable: post, user: current_user, like: params[:like])

Comment: You might add your comment as an answer and "accept" that answer, to make sure your question isn't deleted and others can use it going forward :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my problem shortly after i added this post but decidec not to delete it so someone could get help. I simply added: post = Post.find(params[:id]) Like.create(likeable: post, user: current_user, like: params[:like])